# Optimize contentProvider query for retrieve contact names and phones

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider

Currently, I'm using this code in order to get the contact name and the phone number:

```
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();

    Cursor people = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    int nameIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
    int idIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
    int hasPhoneNumberIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);

    String name, id;
    int hasPhoneNumber;

    while(people.moveToNext()){
        name = people.getString(nameIndex);
        id = people.getString(idIndex);
        hasPhoneNumber = people.getInt(hasPhoneNumberIndex);

        if(hasPhoneNumber > 0){
            Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+id, null, null);
            phones.moveToFirst();

            int phoneIndex = phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
            String phone = phones.getString(phoneIndex);

            HashMap<String, String> namePhoneType = new HashMap<String, String>();
            namePhoneType.put("Name", name);
            namePhoneType.put("Phone", phone);

            m_peopleList.add(namePhoneType);

            phones.close();
        }
    }
```

But this is extremely slow.

Is there a way to retrieve name and phone in only one query?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**I've founded a way:**

```
Cursor people = getContentResolver()
.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
new String[] {Phone._ID, Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER}, null, null,  Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems to me that the noted performance issue stems from the inherent "n+1 select" problem in the implementations proposed.

1. open a cursor to iterate over all contacts (1)
2. for each contact open a cursor to iterate over the phone numbers for that contact (n)

A faster approach, if you truly need all this data, is to perform two queries from contacts and phone numbers returning the appropriate surrogate and primary keys and then performing the join in memory.

Query 1: get all contacts as a Map by ContactId

```
With the myriad of solutions proposed being sure to pull out the _ID field as the ContactId
```

Query 2: get all the phone numbers and store them in a list

```
        Cursor c = MyO2Application.getContext().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER },
                null,
                null,
                null
        );
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            String id = c.getString(0);
            String contactId = c.getString(1);  // this is the foreign key to the contact primary key
            String displayName = c.getString(2);
            String number = c.getString(3);
```

You can then iterate through the list of phone numbers, looking up the contact from the map by ContactId and associate the phone numbers with the contact.

Execution speeds for 1000 contacts went from 60 seconds down to 4 seconds.  As is often the case, there is a trade-off on memory consumption and impact to GC.

Observation while posting: getting the ids as an int and using SparseArray may be an approach worth considering.  Minimal impact expected, however, compared to the "n+1 select" issue addressed here.

Comment: I've seen a lot of possible solutions to this issue, but this one's the best by FAR!!!

Comment: How do I get Photos of contact along with this in one query.

Comment: What do you mean by GC?

Comment: Garbage Collection; You are pulling up a lot of repeated data which results in more objects on the heap for the Garbage Collector to work through.  Not really an issue these days as the GC is heavily optimized

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about how to do it in a different way [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/retrieving-contact-information-name-number-and-profile-picture/)

Here's a snippet

```
//query for the people in your address book
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,People.NAME + " ASC");
startManagingCursor(cursor);

//bind the name and the number fields
String[] columns = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.name_entry, R.id.number_entry };
SimpleContactAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleContactAdapter(this, R.layout.list_entry, cursor, columns, to);
this.setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: In that post says that the code is only for "This post is for API levels 4 or lower"